# How can I return an object from a function without it outputting "NameSpaxe.ObjectName"?

Tags: c#

Pretty basic question but I'm attempting to use a function to generate two random numbers, put them in an object and then return that object to whatever called the function.
The way I have it set up currently is:

```
public class Numbers
{
    public int NumberOne { get; set; }
    public int NumberTwo { get; set; }
    public Numbers(int num1, int num2)
    {
        NumberOne = num1;
        NumberTwo = num2;
    }
}

public object GenerateQuestion()
{
    int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
    int num2 = rnd.next(1, 11);
    Numbers question = new Numbers(num1, num2);
    return question;
}

public page()
{
    // I want the returned object here
    label1.Text =  // I want to access the object like Object.NumberOne
    label2.Text =  // I want to access the object like Object.NumberTwo
}
```

Apologies if I haven't stated what I want properly but I tried.

Comment: don't return `object` - return `Numbers` from `GenerateQuestion`

Comment: Why do you return an _object_ instead of _Numbers_?

Comment: I'm from a javascript descendant trying to figure out objects lol. Thanks I will try it out. Yep it worked I appreciate it

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question body. If you're seeing "Namespace.ClassName" then it means you are calling `ToString` on your object (explicitly or implicitly). When you don't override `ToString` in your class, the default implementation returns the class' name

Comment: It's already fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you return object from `GenerateQuestion()`

You can use like that ;

```
var generatedQuestion = (Numbers)GenerateQuestion();
label1.Text =  generatedQuestion.NumberOne.ToString();
label2.Text =  generatedQuestion.NumberTwo.ToString();
```

If you return Numbers from `GenerateQuestion()`

like that

```
public Numbers GenerateQuestion()
{
    int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11);
    int num2 = rnd.next(1, 11);
    Numbers question = new Numbers(num1, num2);
    return question;
}
```

You can use like that ;

```
var generatedQuestion = GenerateQuestion();
label1.Text =  generatedQuestion.NumberOne.ToString();
label2.Text =  generatedQuestion.NumberTwo.ToString();
```

Comment: Except `NumberOne` and `NumberTwo` are `int`s so you'll need a `ToString`  when assigning to `Text`